# How should AWSRequestInfo.json look like?

Tags: .net-core, monitoring, aws-xray

This file is mentioned only [once](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22AWSRequestInfo.json%22) on the internet. However, I need it for my

[x-ray monitoring library](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet/tree/master) to refer to it from my appsettings file. How should it look like?

Answer (score 4):

The default json used by X-Ray SDK for .NET And .NET Core is : [Link](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/sdk/src/Handlers/AwsSdk/DefaultAWSWhitelist.json)

The use of `AwsServiceHandlerManifest` attribute in configuration is optional : [Link](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet/tree/master#configuration)

You can follow this json [file](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/sdk/src/Handlers/AwsSdk/DefaultAWSWhitelist.json) to define your custom `AWSRequestInfo.json` and add desired AWS services.

We (the AWS X-Ray team) are very active on the AWS X-Ray official forum. We're much more likely to quickly respond to future posts if they're made to the [X-Ray specific forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=241&start=0).

Thanks,

Yogi